# How to set objects on Spring 3.1 MVC controller from an interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I'm having a couple of issues related to interceptors since upgrading to 3.1. In version 3.0.x and earlier I used the following pattern to intercept Spring MVC controllers:

1. Create an interface called something like RoleAware which defines one or more setters.
2. Have one or more controllers implement the interface
3. Register a new global interceptor which does a "handler instanceof RoleAware" check in the preHandle
4. If the interceptor is an instanceof RoleAware, then set one or more objects on the implementing controller

The first issue is that something changed in 3.1 so the instanceof check fails. I've fixed this by using the new explicit  elements in my servlet context configuration. Not a big deal and a bit cleaner approach than the instanceof check.

The second issue is that when I attempt to cast the handler (Controller) to my RoleAware interface I get a ClassCastException.

I'd like a solution that will enable me to continue to arbitrarily set objects on the intercepted controllers. For example, set a Role object on any Controllers that are intercepted. Also, I'd like to know more about the changes in 3.1 that is causing this to break.

Comment: Good question, especially since the API doc for the handler argument says: "handler - chosen handler to execute, for type and/or instance evaluation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) says:

> When using the RequestMappingHandlerMapping the actual handler is an
>   instance of HandlerMethod which identifies the specific controller
>   method that will be invoked.

So I guess that you should just cast the handler to `HandlerMethod`, call its `getBean()` method, and check is the returned bean is an instance of `RoleAware`.

Not tested though. You could try using a debugger to inspect the handler argument and see what it is if it is neither the handler itself, nor the HandlerMethod.

Comment: Yes, I found this to be true and confirmed via test. The handler changed from being the Controller class to the HandlerMethod wrapper class. Although not ideal, I now have to cast the handler to HandlerMethod for my check at the beginning of the preHandle method and cast again to my interface in order to set my objects.